# Postgres: как узнать значение text not float

Tags: sql, postgresql

В базе поле хранится как текст.

Как мне узнать какие строки не могут быть приведены к `float`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

есть 3 варианта

1. вариант - проверка строки, можно ли перевести на число (`int` или `float`)

   ```
   SELECT  ('123.23' ~ '^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$') // true - первый вариант

   SELECT  ('123.23' ~ '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+$)?') // Модифицирован от @ApInvert в комментариях
   ```

возвращает **TRUE**

но если число **123** тогда результат **FALSE**

2. вариант (дополнение к 1му)

   ```
   SELECT  ('123' ~ '^[0-9]+$') OR ('123' ~ '^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$')
   ```

возвращает **TRUE**

3. вариант

создаете функцию

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnumeric(text) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    x = $1::NUMERIC;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

и используете в запросах

```
SELECT x, isnumeric(x) FROM test;
```

Comment: В первом варианте Вы можете немного модифицировать выражение, чтобы и 123.23 подходил и 123 тоже подходил вот так: `'^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+$)?'` [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3632)

Comment: прошу заметить что ваш вариант несколько неправильный ибо 123,23 тоже пройдет